# Can anyone help styling a view in drupal?

Tags: css, drupal, view, slideshow, styling

I'm trying to style a views-slideshow on my Drupal site, once I know how to style one part of the slideshow I can then style the rest. I have this div on the view that i want to style and I'm having trouble even putting a border color on it? the div is ...

```
<div class="views-field views-field-field-slide-image">
```

If anyone can help as to how to style it and where that would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a old link, but I'm sure that it's useful for you:

[http://www.group42.ca/theming_views_2_the_basics](http://www.group42.ca/theming%5fviews%5f2%5fthe%5fbasics)

Basically you have to create new files and put it in your theme.
The name of your files depends on the view. And the module recomends names.

On the other hand, you can add the border using CSS, add this for example:

```
.views-field-field-slide-image {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I managed to have a play around and i've been able to do it! Thanks again